# Structural directive for lazy loading a component in angular 5

Tags: angular, observable, angular-directive, angular2-changedetection, intersection-observer

I am trying to create a structural directive, which lazy loads the components. I am using createEmbeddedViews function to add the components to the template ref as siblings. I need to check on the last sibling if it is in view port then trigger to add more siblings. This continues untill the last added component goes out of view port. The sample code is,

```
for(i=0;i<componentsVisible;i++){
   this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
}

this.intersectionObserver.observe(" Here i need to add the last sibling added");
```

the intersection observer is watched and the components visible will be increased and the for loop will be again called to add more siblings. Facing an issue here to pass the last sibling. The last sibling is available when all the siblings completes rendering. But the function intersection.observe is called right after the for loop. Need Help!!!... Thanks